# jQuery - $.post doesn't post to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am trying to use jQuery to post a variable to the same page using the following code

`file.js`

```
$('#sidebar-nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post(location.href, {theID: theID});
});
```

`file.php`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['theID'])) {
    // do something
    }
?>

<html>
    <!-- the rest of the page -->
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

**But `theID` is not posted to the php file for some reason. My code inside the `if` statement won't execute. In addition, I used this exactly same method for other `removeID` in the same js and same php files, it's working well for `removeID`, but not `theID`.**

**And to clarify what `location.href` is in this situation; it is `file.php`.**

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: What is supposed to happen? Using `$.post()` like that should make the request to your PHP, but there would be no visible changes to the page in the browser. By "this doesn't work" do you mean your PHP doesn't receive the request, or...?

Comment: location.href is what? We can't guess your variables. They're variable.

Comment: sorry for the unclear statement, I updated the question. My php file didn't get the request.

Comment: also `{"theID": theID}`

Comment: @LozCherone - In most cases you don't need quotes around the property names in an object literal. (And this is not one of the cases where you do.)

Comment: @Lancelot - Are there any errors displayed in the browser's console?

Comment: @nnnnnn There is no errors in the console

Comment: @Jimbo `location.href` is a property that you can use for getting current URL. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Comment: What Jimbo means is what is the current value of `location.href` at the time you use it...

Comment: It is `file.php` (the current URL I have when I send the post request.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean :) basic debugging...

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
var theID = $(this).attr('id'));
//           -----------------^
```

You need to remove the extra closing `)`. Or even better don't call two functions when the property can be accessed directly:

```
var theID = this.id;
```

Or better still, since `theID` is used in only one place get rid of that variable altogether:

```
$.post(location.href, {theID: this.id});
```

Comment: Sorry, that extra closing `)` was a mistake when I copied the code to here. And I do need the var on separate line to parse the ID.

Comment: _"I do need the var on separate line to parse the ID."_ - OK, well my suggestion was based on the code shown where you don't do anything else with the variable. But `this.id` is still better than `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the better way to retrieve the ID. Do you know the reason that my php file is not getting the request?

Answer (score 0):

To send ajax request to the same page you can keep url parameter empty/removed

TRY

```
<script type="text/javascript">


           $.post({
                  theID: theID,
                  success: function (data) {
                     alert("Data Loaded:");
                  }
              });

</script>
```

Comment: That won't work. `$.post()` expects the first parameter to be a URL, unless you're saying there is a feature not mentioned on [the `$.post()` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). But even if it expected an object, it wouldn't know about a property called `theID` in the same object as `success`.